# Tell bundler to use TLS v1.2

Tags: bundler, tls1.2

The system on which our Github Enterprise server resides recently underwent a security upgrade, and now no longer supports TLS v1.0. We host a gem on that github server, which is retrieved by `bundler` via https using an `x-oauth-basic` token, like so:

```
gem 'our_gem', git: 'https://abcdef123456abcdef123456:x-oauth-basic@github.our-company.com/department/our_gem.git', require: false
```

Since the security upgrade, `bundle install` has started failing with:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://abcdef123456abcdef123456:x-oauth-basic@github.our-company.com/department/our_gem.git': Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version.
```

I have verified that the version of Ruby and OpenSSL we have do support TLS v1.2 - so how can we force bundler to use TLS v1.2?